# How to make IntelliJ IDEA resolve webpack requires out of node_modules directory?

Tags: javascript, intellij-idea, webpack, reactjs

IntelliJ cannot resolve javascript modules called with webpack requires which are not inside the `node_modules` directory

Imagine this project structure:

```
`- project
   |- node_modules
   |  `- react
   |     `- addons.js
   |- webpack.config.js
   |- util
   |  `- tool.js
   `- src
      |- components
      |  `- uno.jsx
      `- two.jsx
```

This is my webpack config

```js
// webpack.config.js
var path = require('path'); 
module.exports = {
  resolve: {
    root: [
      path.resolve('./src'),
      path.resolve('./')
    ]
  }
  ...
}
```

And this is how I use webpack's require

```js
// two.js
var React = require('react/addons');
var One = require('components/one');
var Tool = require('util/tool');
// dosomething
```

So this works perfectly within my application, and IntelliJ looks happy with 'react/addons', how to make understand the sources for navigation, code completion and Documentation lookup for 'components/one' and 'util/tool'?

I've tried so far:

- adding a package.json inside src (npm init)
- adding src as a Javascript library in Settings / Languages & Frameworks following this https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/configuring-javascript-libraries.html
- mimicking anything below .idea related to node_modules

But no luck so far. Thanks.

Comment: With the complex path resolution patterns that are described in Webpack config file, IJ can't guarantee that all methods are resolved without specific Webpack support. Please vote for the [feature request](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-14019) and follow the updates.

PS: however for me things work pretty good in sample [react-starter](https://github.com/webpack/react-starter) project.

Comment: @EkaterinaPrigara Thanks for the tip. Renaming `src` to `app` did the trick! But things like `import { Row, Column } from 'react-bootstrap';` still won't work while `var reactBootstrap = require('react-bootstrap');` still does. This won't work in [react-starter](https://github.com/webpack/react-starter). I'm not answering my own question because I don't know why all this black magic happens.

Comment: this seems to work when you use the `resolve.root` approach as here (no idea why it doesn't allow src though.) It also works with `resolve.alias` but your alias has to be the same as the root folder name or it ain't going to work :(.

Comment: Oh, my friend. After 1 year later, have still no hope from future.

Comment: you can do to settings, then to project folders, and set some folders als lib folders, this should work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this should work (or so it did in my case anyway).

In IntelliJ:

1. Open the project
2. `File` > `Project Structure`
3. On the left hand side, select `Modules`
4. From your directory structure, select the folders where your sources are (`util` and `src`) and mark them as **Resources**
5. Click `Apply`

You should have code completion and documentation available now.

Comment: The answer is correct. They fixed it some time ago, still messes up refactoring though. In mac the option is under WebStorm > Preferences > Directories.

Comment: Is there anything required after hitting apply? I made `/src` a resource root, src contains `/utils, /components` etc, but I don't get intellisense when cmd - clicking on my import paths. Any ideas?