# IntelliJ Javascript "Cannot Find Declaration to go to" when using custom module path

Tags: javascript, node.js, intellij-idea, webpack, node-modules

I'm trying to use Javascript ES6 import syntax with WebPack configured to use `client` and `node_modules` as root paths for resolving imports.

IntelliJ Idea discovers modules from "node_modules" directory, but it cannot resolve paths from "client" directory.

For example:

When im using:

- `import ImmutableStore from 'alt/utils/ImmutableUtil';` - IntelliJ finds proper paths, because `alt` module is on `node_modules` directory
- `import CustomiserActions from 'js/actions/Customiser.actions.js';` - It doesn't work, because `js` module is in `client` directory.

I've tried many options in module settings/project settings/marking directory as source roots/adding external libraries but nothing seems to work.

IntelliJ Idea version: 14.1.5

Comment: The issue is that IntelliJ does not have a proper support to webpack, check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31164331/how-to-make-intellij-idea-resolve-webpack-requires-out-of-node-modules-directory, they are actively development this feature to the next version of Webstorm, i guess that in a next version of intellj this going to be included.

Answer (score 7):

I know this is old thread. Just for reference, mark the parent directory(in this case 'js') as 'Resource Root,' then Intellisense will work on 2016 version.

Comment: this should be marked as the right answer. Quick and easy fix

Answer (score 2):

What worked for me:

File > Invalidate Caches / Restart...

Answer (score 1):

Based on my own experience, IntelliJ will by default search for the source file in the `node_modules` directory unless it's a relative path like this:

```
import CustomiserActions from './js/actions/Customiser.actions.js';
```

Depending on how your project is structured/build, this might be a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I had a Javascript project and *.js files was not recognized as a javascript file (Note the icon with JS) but rather as a text file.

```
IntelliJ -> Preferences... -> Editor -> File Types
```

Make sure *.js extension is listed under **JavaScript** and absent for **Text** file types