# IntelliJ - Constants show up as unused if accessed via aliases

Tags: javascript, intellij-idea, webpack

Since webpack 3 (and older versions using plugins, I believe) it is possible to add aliases to folder paths, so as to replace highly nested and complicated paths such as '../../../../Some/File' with 'Some/File'.

Inside IntelliJ, everything works as it should one way (ctrl+click on an aliased absolute path navigates to the correct path), but in the destination file, the usage check that grays out unused constants does not see that constant is used, albeit from an aliased path.

Is there a way to tell IntelliJ to inspect more closely and to resolve these links both ways?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the wording is quite different from this other question which answers it I do not think that it should be considered as a duplicate.
However the answer from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31164331/how-to-make-intellij-idea-resolve-webpack-requires-out-of-node-modules-directory) worked for me.

TL;DR: no plugin needed, file -> project settings -> modules and mark your source folders as '**resources**', then apply and IntelliJ will re-index your project and resolve the aliased links between files.